# Postfix - Only allow relaying when sent from local user

Tags: postfix, dmarc, e-mailrelay

At the moment, our Postfix + Dovecot mail system has two types of users: those with a full account and those with only a forwarder.

Users with a full account are in the virtual_aliases table pointing to the local mailbox (e.g. `compuchip@example.com --> compuchip/`, I'm not sure that's strictly necessary btw) and have some aliases (e.g. `c.chip@example.com --> compuchip`).

Users with a forwarder have their personal account in the aliases table, and potentially aliases as well (e.g. `compuchip@example.com --> compuchip@gmail.or.hotmail.com`) as well as `c.chip@example.com --> compuchip`).

Because I'm forwarding a lot of spam to the last group of users we often get blacklisted and I want to shut this down. I decided that if users want to send and receive external mail I should just give them a mailbox. But if possible I would like that everyone can continue to be reached from "inside". Let me describe that more accurately:

- if a user has a mailbox (the virtual aliases eventually resolve to a local destination) email from anyone should be accepted
- if the user does not (all of their aliases point at other aliases or external domains) I only want to accept (and therefore relay) email originating from within my domain (anyone@example.com)

I have DKIM / SPF / DMARC setup, could I do something with that? I think that forwarding nonlocal mail to a nonlocal recipient will fail SPF if I disable SRS, could I just configure it to reject email in those cases?

Comment: There's several delivery issues with email forwarding. One is that your server also forwards it spam it receives to the final recipient. Your server/IP-address will be seen as the source of that spam by the final recipients anti-spam solution resulting in your IP getting blocked. You partly solve that by aggressive spam filtering. - The second issue is that [email forwarding breaks with SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#FAIL_and_forwarding) .

Comment: The *"solution"* to deal with how traditional e-mail forwarding breaks SPF is **SRS** ; the [Sender Rewriting Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme) - see for example https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd - I don't think you need a local mailbox for that.

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn. I'm currently using srs but the spam filtering isn't aggressive enough. So I am rather looking to get rid of the whole thing. But it would be nice if I can keep the forward working for senders from the local domain (or, alternatively, whitelisted senders) so colleagues can find each other without having to look up a private email address.